# Saving models from Python

Tags: python, serialization

Is it possible to save a predictive model in Python?

**Background**: I'm building regression models in SPSS and I need to share those when done. Unfortunately, no one else has SPSS.

**Idea**: My idea is to make the model in Python, do something XYZ, use another library to convert XYZ into and exe that will pick up a csv file with data and spit out the model fit results on that data. In this way, I can share the model with anyone I want without the need of SPSS or other expensive software

**Challenge**: I need to find out XYZ, how do I save the instance when the model is built. For example, in case of linear/logistic, it would be the set of coefficients.

PS: I'm using linear/logistic as examples, in reality, I need to share more complex models like SVM etc.

Comment: You can save/load almost any Python object to/from a file using the standard `cPickle` library. If your model is represented as a Python class with lists and dicts and tuples (or even numpy arrays) in it, this should work. It may not be the most efficient way though.

Answer (score 2):

Using FOSS (Free & Open Source Software) is great to facilitate collaboration.  Consider using [R](http://www.r-project.org) or [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org) (which has a Python backbone and includes R) so that you can freely share programs and data.  Or even use [Sagemath Cloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com) so that you can work collaboratively in real-time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. What you're looking for is [scitkit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/) in combination with [joblib](http://pythonhosted.org/joblib/). A working example of your problem can be found in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592605/save-naivebayes-classifier-to-disk-in-scikits-learn).