# Classifying new occurances - Multinomial Naive Bayes

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn

So I have currently trained a Multinomial Naive Bayes classifier, using `[SKiLearn][1]`
Now what I can do is classify test data by using predict.

But if I want to run this every night, as a script, I clearly need to always have a classifier already trained up! Now what I'd like to be able to do, is take classifier coefficients, informative words, and use these to classify new data.

Is this possible - to develop my own method for classification? Or should I be simply training the SkiLearn classifier nightly?

EDIT: One thing, it seems I can do, is retain and [save my trained classifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592605/save-naivebayes-classifier-to-disk-in-scikits-learn).

However with logistic regression, you can take the coefficients and use these on new data. Is there anything similar to this for NB?

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't just want to save and load the classifier as necessary.

Comment: What do you mean by "take the coefficients and use these on new data"? All ML algorithms are designed to be trained and then used to predict outputs on **new**, **unseen** data.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean [sklearn]? Are you using python? If that is the case, it turns out that [sklearn] provides a function for getting the parameters of the model [get_params(deep=True)] as well as a function for setting them [set_params(**params)].

Therefore, a possible procedure could be:

Training stage:

1) Train the model

2) Get the parameters of the model by using get_params()

3) Save the parameters into a binary file (e.g. by using pickle.dump())

Prediction stage:

1) Load the parameters of the model from the binary file (e.g. by using pickle.load())

2) Set the parameters of the model by using set_params()

3) Classify new data by using the predict() function

Hope that helps.