# scikit-learn model persistence: pickle vs pmml vs ...?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, pmml

I built an [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/) model and I want to reuse in a daily python cron job (**NB**: no other platforms are involved - no R, no Java &c).

I [pickled](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) it (actually, I pickled my own object whose one field is a [`GradientBoostingClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html)), and I un-pickle it in the cron job. So far so good (and has been discussed in [Save classifier to disk in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10592605/850781) and [Model persistence in Scikit-Learn?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38320910/850781)).

However, I upgraded `sklearn` and now I get these warnings:

```
.../.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:315: 
UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator DecisionTreeRegressor from version 0.18.1 when using version 0.18.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
UserWarning)
.../.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:315: 
UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator PriorProbabilityEstimator from version 0.18.1 when using version 0.18.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
UserWarning)
.../.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:315: 
UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator GradientBoostingClassifier from version 0.18.1 when using version 0.18.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
UserWarning)
```

**What do I do now?**

- I can downgrage to 0.18.1 and stick with it until I am ready to rebuild the model. For various reasons I find this unacceptable.
- I can un-pickle the file and re-pickle it again. This worked with 0.18.2, but **breaks with 0.19**. NFG. [`joblib`](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/persistence.html) looks no better.
- I wish I could save the data in a version-independent ASCII format (e.g., JSON or XML). This is, obviously, the optimal solution, but there seems to be *NO* way to do that (see also [Sklearn - model persistence without pkl file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37033910/850781)).
- I could save the model to [PMML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_Model_Markup_Language), but its support is lukewarm at best:
  I can use [`sklearn2pmml`](https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml) to *save* the model (although not easily), and [`augustus`](https://github.com/opendatagroup/augustus)/[`lightpmmlpredictor`](https://github.com/ctrl-alt-d/lightpmmlpredictor) to *apply* (although **not** load) the model. However, none of those is available to `pip` directly, which makes deployment a nightmare. Also, the `augustus` & `lightpmmlpredictor` projects seem to be dead. [Importing PMML models into Python (Scikit-learn)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40048987/850781) - nope.
- A variant of the above: save PMML using `sklearn2pmml`, and use [`openscoring`](https://github.com/openscoring/openscoring) for scoring. Requires interfacing with an external process. Yuk.

**Suggestions?**

Answer (score 5):

Model persistence across different versions of scikit-learn is generally impossible. The reason is obvious: you pickle `Class1` with one definition, and want to unpickle it into `Class2` with another definition.

You can:

- Still try to stick to one version of sklearn.
- Ignore the warnings and hope that what worked for `Class1` will work also for `Class2`.
- Write your own class that can serialize your `GradientBoostingClassifier` and restore it from this serialized form, and hope that it would work better than pickle.

I made an example of how you can convert a single `DecisionTreeRegressor` into a pure list-and-dict format, fully JSON-compatible, and restore it back.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

### Code to serialize and deserialize trees

LEAF_ATTRIBUTES = ['children_left', 'children_right', 'threshold', 'value', 'feature', 'impurity', 'weighted_n_node_samples']
TREE_ATTRIBUTES = ['n_classes_', 'n_features_', 'n_outputs_']

def serialize_tree(tree):
    """ Convert a sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor into a json-compatible format """
    encoded = {
        'nodes': {},
        'tree': {},
        'n_leaves': len(tree.tree_.threshold),
        'params': tree.get_params()
    }
    for attr in LEAF_ATTRIBUTES:
        encoded['nodes'][attr] = getattr(tree.tree_, attr).tolist()
    for attr in TREE_ATTRIBUTES:
        encoded['tree'][attr] = getattr(tree, attr)
    return encoded

def deserialize_tree(encoded):
    """ Restore a sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor from a json-compatible format """
    x = np.arange(encoded['n_leaves'])
    tree = DecisionTreeRegressor().fit(x.reshape((-1,1)), x)
    tree.set_params(**encoded['params'])
    for attr in LEAF_ATTRIBUTES:
        for i in range(encoded['n_leaves']):
            getattr(tree.tree_, attr)[i] = encoded['nodes'][attr][i]
    for attr in TREE_ATTRIBUTES:
        setattr(tree, attr, encoded['tree'][attr])
    return tree

## test the code

X, y = make_classification(n_classes=3, n_informative=10)
tree = DecisionTreeRegressor().fit(X, y)
encoded = serialize_tree(tree)
decoded = deserialize_tree(encoded)
assert (decoded.predict(X)==tree.predict(X)).all()
```

Having this, you can go on to serialize and deserialize the whole `GradientBoostingClassifier`:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble.gradient_boosting import PriorProbabilityEstimator

def serialize_gbc(clf):
    encoded = {
        'classes_': clf.classes_.tolist(),
        'max_features_': clf.max_features_, 
        'n_classes_': clf.n_classes_,
        'n_features_': clf.n_features_,
        'train_score_': clf.train_score_.tolist(),
        'params': clf.get_params(),
        'estimators_shape': list(clf.estimators_.shape),
        'estimators': [],
        'priors':clf.init_.priors.tolist()
    }
    for tree in clf.estimators_.reshape((-1,)):
        encoded['estimators'].append(serialize_tree(tree))
    return encoded

def deserialize_gbc(encoded):
    x = np.array(encoded['classes_'])
    clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(**encoded['params']).fit(x.reshape(-1, 1), x)
    trees = [deserialize_tree(tree) for tree in encoded['estimators']]
    clf.estimators_ = np.array(trees).reshape(encoded['estimators_shape'])
    clf.init_ = PriorProbabilityEstimator()
    clf.init_.priors = np.array(encoded['priors'])
    clf.classes_ = np.array(encoded['classes_'])
    clf.train_score_ = np.array(encoded['train_score_'])
    clf.max_features_ = encoded['max_features_']
    clf.n_classes_ = encoded['n_classes_']
    clf.n_features_ = encoded['n_features_']
    return clf

# test on the same problem
clf = GradientBoostingClassifier()
clf.fit(X, y);
encoded = serialize_gbc(clf)
decoded = deserialize_gbc(encoded)
assert (decoded.predict(X) == clf.predict(X)).all()
```

This works for scikit-learn v0.19, but don't ask me what will come in the next versions to break this code. I'm neither a prophet nor a developer of sklearn.

If you want to be fully independent of new versions of sklearn, the safest thing is to write a function that traverses a serialized tree and makes the prediction, instead of re-creating an sklearn tree.

Comment: How is this more reliable than pickle? The problem with pickle is that if `sklearn` changes the Class definition (e.g., drops or renames a slot), I will have to rewrite the `serialize_*` and `deserialize_*` function and, more important, write deserializer that converts the serialization of the _old_ version to the _new_ version. I agree that this is probably better than the pickle nightmare, but hardly much.

Comment: This cannot guarantee that you will be compatible with the 20, or 200 version of sklearn. But it at least gives you more control over the situation. E.g. if sklearn fully rewrites its ```ClassificationLossFunction```, you will not be affected.