# Save MinMaxScaler model in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, normalization

I'm using the `MinMaxScaler` model in sklearn to normalize the features of a model.

```
training_set = np.random.rand(4,4)*10
training_set

       [[ 6.01144787,  0.59753007,  2.0014852 ,  3.45433657],
       [ 6.03041646,  5.15589559,  6.64992437,  2.63440202],
       [ 2.27733136,  9.29927394,  0.03718093,  7.7679183 ],
       [ 9.86934288,  7.59003904,  6.02363739,  2.78294206]]


scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(training_set)    
scaler.transform(training_set)


   [[ 0.49184811,  0.        ,  0.29704831,  0.15972182],
   [ 0.4943466 ,  0.52384506,  1.        ,  0.        ],
   [ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
   [ 1.        ,  0.80357559,  0.9052909 ,  0.02893534]]
```

Now I want to use the same scaler to normalize the test set:

```
   [[ 8.31263467,  7.99782295,  0.02031658,  9.43249727],
   [ 1.03761228,  9.53173021,  5.99539478,  4.81456067],
   [ 0.19715961,  5.97702519,  0.53347403,  5.58747666],
   [ 9.67505429,  2.76225253,  7.39944931,  8.46746594]]
```

But I don't want so use the `scaler.fit()` with the training data all the time. Is there a way to save the scaler and load it later from a different file?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

So I'm actually not an expert with this but from a bit of research and a few helpful [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592605/save-classifier-to-disk-in-scikit-learn), I think `pickle` and `sklearn.externals.joblib` are going to be your friends here.

The package `pickle` lets you save models or "dump" models to a file.

I think this [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html) is also helpful. It talks about creating a persistence model. Something that you're going to want to try is:

```
# could use: import pickle... however let's do something else
from sklearn.externals import joblib 

# this is more efficient than pickle for things like large numpy arrays
# ... which sklearn models often have.   

# then just 'dump' your file
joblib.dump(clf, 'my_dope_model.pkl')
```

[Here](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/generated/joblib.dump.html) is where you can learn more about the sklearn  externals.

Let me know if that doesn't help or I'm not understanding something about your model.

Note: `sklearn.externals.joblib` is deprecated. Install and use the pure `joblib` instead

Comment: For some reason, when I use this to save a `MinMaxScaler`, the loaded scaler doesn't scale the data identically to a freshly fitted scaler. Any idea why?

Comment: @BallpointBen Just tried it on a separate test set and got the same results. Maybe you used `np.random.rand` again?

Answer (score 117):

**Update:** `sklearn.externals.joblib` is deprecated. Install and use the pure `joblib` instead. Please see [Engineero's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56978681/3466910), which is otherwise identical to mine.

#### Original answer

Even better than `pickle` (which creates much larger files than this method), you can use `sklearn`'s built-in tool:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
scaler_filename = "scaler.save"
joblib.dump(scaler, scaler_filename) 

# And now to load...

scaler = joblib.load(scaler_filename)
```

Comment: It's a good solution, but same with pickle isn' it? I'm a beginner in machine learning.

Comment: It is not -- `joblib.dump` is optimized for dumping sklearn objects and therefore creates much smaller files than pickle, which dumps the object with all its dependencies and such.

Comment: My experience with `pickle` is poor: it probably works for a short-term export but over long period of time, you have to deal with protocol version (one of parameters for pickling) and I've encountered errors when loading old exports. I prefer this answer, thus.

Answer (score 41):

Just a note that `sklearn.externals.joblib` has been deprecated and is superseded by plain old [`joblib`](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), which can be installed with `pip install joblib`:

```
import joblib
joblib.dump(my_scaler, 'scaler.gz')
my_scaler = joblib.load('scaler.gz')
```

Note that file extensions can be anything, but if it is one of `['.z', '.gz', '.bz2', '.xz', '.lzma']` then the corresponding compression protocol will be used. Docs for [`joblib.dump()`](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.dump.html) and [`joblib.load()`](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.load.html) methods.

Answer (score 22):

You can use `pickle`, to save the scaler:

```
import pickle
scalerfile = 'scaler.sav'
pickle.dump(scaler, open(scalerfile, 'wb'))
```

Load it back:

```
import pickle
scalerfile = 'scaler.sav'
scaler = pickle.load(open(scalerfile, 'rb'))
test_scaled_set = scaler.transform(test_set)
```

Answer (score 14):

#### The best way to do this is to create an ML pipeline like the following:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.externals import joblib


pipeline = make_pipeline(MinMaxScaler(),YOUR_ML_MODEL() )

model = pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

#### Now you can save it to a file:

```
joblib.dump(model, 'filename.mod')
```

#### Later you can load it like this:

```
model = joblib.load('filename.mod')
```

Comment: You can use joblib or pickle here. The point is to create a pipeline so that you don’t have to separately call the scaler.

Comment: This is _instead_ of saving the model, correct? If so, this seems like a better answer than the above, as you don't have to manage two separate files.