# How can I save my trained SVM model to retrieve it later for time saving in python?

Tags: python, svm

I'm new to python and working on machine learning. I have trained LinearSVC from sklearn.svm, and training takes quite a long time, mostly because of stemming (7-8 minutes), I want to know if it is possible to save model results as some extension that can be fed as it is back to python when running the application, just to save the time of the training happening in every run of the application..

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/10593176/6524169

Answer (score 1):

My Answer:-

Pickle or Joblib is used to save a trained model

For your reference, check it out the link given below.

[Reference Link](http://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-machine-learning-models-python-scikit-learn/)

Comment: I tried using it but I get an error.  'AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Stemmed' on <module '__main__' from '~/classification.py'> '. Should I save my training documents as well? if so, help me to know how! :D

Comment: No. I think you need not to save your documents. Just replace the url with your training set from your local disk. That's it