# What is the best way to save sklearn model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am working on a python desktop app. This app does some predictions. Right now I train my sklearn model using python script, save the parameters of the model as a dictionary in a yaml file. Then, I build in this yaml into my python app. Then, when I am using the app, the model is recreated using parameters from the dictionary. I realized, that people who have a different version of sklearn get an error. I tried to save my model in a pickle file, but in this case, it produced some warning when app was running on a machine with a different version of sklearn.

Answer (score 4):

There is no guarantee that a given sklearn model would be compatible between versions of sklearn. Indeed, the implementation or the internal API may change between versions. See more informations [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html).

If you consider one version, the best way is indeed to pickle, and not to save the parameters in a yaml file. It's even better to use joblib to do so. See more informations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592605/save-classifier-to-disk-in-scikit-learn).

Answer (score 4):

> I realized, that people who have a different version of sklearn get an error.

In this case, create isolated Python environments using [virtualenvs](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can just generate a Python code from a trained model. This way you eliminate any possibility of object incompatibility. Here is a tool that can help with that https://github.com/BayesWitnesses/m2cgen