# How to save scikit-learn MULTIPLE classifier models with python pickle library (or any efficient others)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle

In general, we could use pickle to save [ONE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592605/save-classifier-to-disk-in-scikit-learn) classifier model. Is there a way to save MULTIPLE classifier models in one pickle? If yes, how could we save the model and retrieve it later?

For instance, (the minimum working example)

```
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from numpy.random import rand, randint 

models = []
models.append(('LogisticReg', LogisticRegression(random_state=123)))
models.append(('DecisionTree', DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=123)))
# evaluate each model in turn
results_all = []
names = []
dict_method_score = {}
scoring = 'f1'

X = rand(8, 4)
Y = randint(2, size=8)

print("Method: Average (Standard Deviation)\n")
for name, model in models:
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=2, random_state=999)
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X, Y, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
    results_all.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    dict_method_score[name] = (cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print("{:s}: {:.3f} ({:.3f})".format(name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std()))
```

Purpose: Change some hyperparameters (say n_splits in cross validation) using the same setup and retrieve the model later.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I was thinking to save the "model". But as what @RyanWalker has suggested, essentially those are just objects.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can save multiple objects into the same pickle:

```
with open("models.pckl", "wb") as f:
    for model in models:
         pickle.dump(model, f)
```

You can then load back your models into memory one at a time:

```
models = []
with open("models.pckl", "rb") as f:
    while True:
        try:
            models.append(pickle.load(f))
        except EOFError:
            break
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice and clean response.