# Means to save a Python kmodes clustering model to disk?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, hdf5

## Background

I am currently using the [`kmodes` python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/kmodes/) to perform unsupervised learning on data that includes categorical parameters.

I need to be able to **save** these models, as I am planning to use it in a production pipeline where I wish to be able to "roll back" to older, working models if something in the pipeline fails.

## Requirements

I can use any file format, including [HDF5 format](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/quick.html).  I am also not wedded to `kmodes`, however I do need to be able to handle mixed categorical and numerical data.

---

## Help

I cannot seem to find ***any*** way that I can save the full `kmodes` model to disk, but I'm hoping that I'm just missing something obvious.  Please provide any potential options.

Comment: Please provide the reason for downvote.  Is the question unclear?  There is no need for sample data, for instance.  It seems both self sufficient and self evident.

Comment: Can you provide an example? In @chthonicdaemon example the data returned by KModes is a simple and highly correlated numpy array, which can be very efficiently saved in a compressed HDF5-Format.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson I would appreciate some additional comments on why one of the answers isn't good enough...

Comment: @chthonicdaemon Your answer was good enough.  I got sidetracked with other work and didn't come back to this page for a few days.  Thanks so much!  Very helpful, in fact!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's start with the example clustering from the [project's README](https://github.com/nicodv/kmodes#usage):

```
import numpy as np
from kmodes.kmodes import KModes

# random categorical data
data = np.random.choice(20, (100, 10))

km = KModes(n_clusters=4, init='Huang', n_init=5, verbose=1)

clusters = km.fit_predict(data)
```

We can now save this using the pickle module:

```
import pickle

# It is important to use binary access
with open('km.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(km, f)
```

To read back the object, use

```
with open('km.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    km = pickle.load(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the kmodes and kprototypes classes inherit from scikit learn’s BaseEstimator. In sklearn, you can save/load a trained model via standard serialization, using pickle.

Here’s a link to sklearn docs on saving a model using pickle or the serialization code from joblib: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html

Does this answer address your problem? Are the kmodes models not serializable in your application?

Comment: Thanks, @svohara!  It was not obvious to me at first that `kmodes` was inheriting from `BaseEstimator`.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the Python [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) library.

> The pickle module implements an algorithm for turning an arbitrary Python object into a series of bytes. This process is also called serializing” the object. The byte stream representing the object can then be transmitted or stored, and later reconstructed to create a new object with the same characteristics.

I think [this](http://stackabuse.com/scikit-learn-save-and-restore-models/) would be a very helpful resource for you in implementing it.

Another library to look into includes [cPickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-cPickle). Why?

> First, cPickle can be up to 1000 times faster than pickle because the
>   former is implemented in C.

Given you are needing to save your models to disk, it probably means you model is decently big. Time is a priority - and this will save you a ton of time.

> Second, in the cPickle module the
>   callables Pickler() and Unpickler() are functions, not classes. This
>   means that you cannot use them to derive custom pickling and
>   unpickling subclasses. Most applications have no need for this
>   functionality and should benefit from the greatly improved performance
>   of the cPickle module.

So it depends on your program and required functionality. A good example of using cPickle can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592605/save-classifier-to-disk-in-scikit-learn)

Comment: Thanks, @Anna!  I also appreciate the `pickle` v. `cPickle` comparison.  I chose @chthon's for the bounty, though, since it provided an example.