# How to Insert new data to make a prediction? Sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm doing the "Hello world" in machine learning, using the Iris dataset. I already have an acceptable result for the entry of this model, I am using 80% of the information to train it and the remaining 20% ​​to do the validation. I am using 6 prediction algorithms, which work well.

but I have a problem, how can I insert new information so that it is analyzed? How do I insert the characteristics of a flower and tell me the type of iris it is? Either: Iris-setosa, Iris-versicolor or Iris-virginica?

```
# Load libraries
import pandas
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.svm import SVC

# Load dataset
    url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/iris.csv"

names = ['sepal-length', 'sepal-width', 'petal-length', 'petal-width', 'class']
dataset = pandas.read_csv(url, names=names)




#######Evaluate Some Algorithms########


#Create a Validation Dataset
# Split-out validation dataset
array = dataset.values
X = array[:,0:4]
Y = array[:,4]
validation_size = 0.20
seed = 7
X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = model_selection.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=validation_size, random_state=seed)



########Build Models########
# Spot Check Algorithms
models = []
models.append(('LR', LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear', multi_class='ovr')))
models.append(('LDA', LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()))
models.append(('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier()))
models.append(('CART', DecisionTreeClassifier()))
models.append(('NB', GaussianNB()))
models.append(('SVM', SVC(gamma='auto')))
# evaluate each model in turn
results = []
names = []
for name, model in models:
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(msg)


########Make Predictions########
print('######## Make Predictions ########')
# Make predictions on validation dataset
knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
knn.fit(X_train, Y_train)
predictions = knn.predict(X_validation)
print(accuracy_score(Y_validation, predictions))
print(confusion_matrix(Y_validation, predictions))
print(classification_report(Y_validation, predictions))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can follow this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592605/save-classifier-to-disk-in-scikit-learn) to save your model, and after you can load him and pass new data and make some predictions.

Remember to set the data to same input shape as used during training.

```
import cPickle
# save the classifier
with open('my_dumped_classifier.pkl', 'wb') as fid:
    cPickle.dump(gnb, fid)    

# load it again
with open('my_dumped_classifier.pkl', 'rb') as fid:
    gnb_loaded = cPickle.load(fid)

# make predictions
```