# Can't pickle <class 'sklearn.linear_model.logistic.LogisticRegression'>: it's not the same object as sklearn.linear_model.logistic.LogisticRegression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am getting the following error message:

```
Can't pickle <class 'sklearn.linear_model.logistic.LogisticRegression'>: it's not the same object as sklearn.linear_model.logistic.LogisticRegression
```

Here is the code:

```
logR_pipeline_ngram = Pipeline([('LogR_tfidf',FeatureSelection.tfidf_ngram),
    ('LogR_clf',LogisticRegression(penalty="l2",C=1))])

logR_pipeline_ngram.fit(DataPrep.train_news['Statement'],DataPrep.train_news['label'])

model_file = 'final_model.sav'
pickle.dump(logR_pipeline_ngram,open(model_file,'wb'))
```

What is causing this?

Comment: trying to save this model but it returns the error mentioned in the title

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. On the [ask] page you find some help to upgrade your question.

Comment: what would you like to save as a pickle?

Comment: the logRngram model

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save classifier to disk in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592605/save-classifier-to-disk-in-scikit-learn)